# Hibernate: java.sql.SQLException: Attempt to continue working after transaction rolledback

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, transactions, sqlexception

In Hibernate, while fetching an OBJECT from database following error occurred. Can you guys please let me know in what conditions would this error occur ?
Nothing has been changed in the code. The same piece of code has been running successfully for years.

What are the possible reasons for this exception ? Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks a lot :-)

```
java.sql.SQLException: Attempt to continue working after transaction rolledback !
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.toSQLException(AdapterUtil.java:1376)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.beginTransactionIfNecessary(WSJdbcConnection.java:701)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.prepareStatement(WSJdbcConnection.java:2084)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.prepareStatement(WSJdbcConnection.java:2039)
at net.sf.hibernate.impl.BatcherImpl.getPreparedStatement(BatcherImpl.java:257)
at net.sf.hibernate.impl.BatcherImpl.getPreparedStatement(BatcherImpl.java:232)
at net.sf.hibernate.impl.BatcherImpl.prepareQueryStatement(BatcherImpl.java:65)
at net.sf.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:779)
at net.sf.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:265)
at net.sf.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:133)
at net.sf.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:911)
at net.sf.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:931)
at net.sf.hibernate.loader.EntityLoader.load(EntityLoader.java:59)
at net.sf.hibernate.loader.EntityLoader.load(EntityLoader.java:51)
at net.sf.hibernate.persister.EntityPersister.load(EntityPersister.java:419)
at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2117)
at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.doLoadByClass(SessionImpl.java:1991)
at net.sf.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1927)
```

Comment: I think the problem is with server side...

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the code (server side) always had a bug which was simply hidden, because there never was a transaction rollback.

So first, one needs to check, why the transaction now fails (database integrity issue or schema has changed?) and next, one has to add a test that simulates a rollback and fix the server code.